# How to pass an Array as a parameter to a Function/Bifunction?

Tags: java, lambda, euclidean-distance

I need to pass an array as parameter into a `BiFunction`.

*Use case :*

> Calculate the Euclidean Distance of `2` coordinates given in an array.
> `coordinate1` and `coordinate2` are an array.

The below trial, makes the intent clearer.

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Double> euclideanDistance =
   (Integer[] x, Integer[] y) -> Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x[0] - y[0], 2) + Math.pow(x[1] - y[1], 2));
```

But the compiler complains :

```
incompatible types:
incompatible parameter types in lambda expression :
Expected Integer but found Integer[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any reference type as a parameter to the `Function`. Your `BiFunction` should take two `int[]` as it's input and return a `Double`. So, the target type of the assignment should be something like this.

```
BiFunction<int[], int[], Double> euclideanDistance =
                (int[] x, int[] y) -> Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x[0] - y[0], 2) + Math.pow(x[1] - y[1], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The types of function (`Integer`) you've defined don't match expected arguments of your lambda expression (`Integer[]`).

And there's no need to use arrays of wrapper type, as well as no need to resort to `sqrt()` and `pow()` since we have [`hypot()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#hypot(double,double)) method in the `Math` class which does exactly what is needed:

> **Returns:**
> `sqrt(x2 +y2)` without intermediate overflow or underflow

So the function for calculating the Euclidean distance can be written like this:

```
BiFunction<int[], int[], Double> euclideanDistance =
    (int[] x, int[] y) -> Math.hypot(x[0] - y[0], x[1] - y[1]);
```